# How to check If a string contains a sub string?

Tags: android, string

I am getting two strings and trying to check If string A contains string B. but the problem is I am getting the error **The method contains(String) is undefined for the type StringBuilder**. what is this error? and how do I fix this?

```
// 1) get saved link
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String LINK = preferences.getString("random54", "");

    // 2) get text from savedlinks.txt to string
    String sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/X ADB/";
    File file = new File(sdcard, "savedlinks.txt");
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    // 3) check if link already present in the .txt file or not
    if (text.contains(LINK)) {
        // DONT SAVE CAUSE DUPLICATE
    } else {
        // SAVE LINK IN HISTORY
```

Comment: `text.toString().contains(LINK)`

Comment: thanks that worked

Answer (score 2):

Text is a `StringBuilder`, not a `String`.

`if (text.toString().contains(LINK))`

Answer (score 1):

```
text.toString().contains(LINK)
```

Answer (score 1):

StringBuilder class doesn't have contains().

Use toString() to convert to string first.

```
text.toString().contains(LINK)
```

Answer (score 1):

For example
If we want to know if stringvalue contains a spotify url:

```
boolean contains = stringvalue.toLowerCase().contains("https://open.spotify.com/");
```

Comment: This answer is better, because it points out the fact that the `contains()` method is case sensitive, the other answers are correct too but you may use them and still not get results

Answer (score 0):

you can use toString() method on any java object to get a string representation of it and you can even override this method in any class to provide your own toString implementation.

In your case:

```
text.toString().contains(LINK)
```

will do the work (here you are using the toString method of StringBuilder which returns a string representing the data in this sequence)

Note: not all toString returns an expected string especially with arrays and complicated objects